# how can I use includes() function on nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [];
arr = [['red', 685], ['green', 210], ['blue', 65]];
```

Also I have two variables:

```
var color  = 'blue';
var number = 21;
```

All I'm trying to do is checking the first item of each nested array of `arr` and then either update the second item of it or make a new array for it.

Here is some examples:

**Input:**

```
var color  = 'blue';
var number = 21;
```

**Expected output:**

```
arr = [['red', 685], ['green', 210], ['blue', 21]];
```

---

**Input:**

```
var color  = 'yellow';
var number = 245;
```

**Expected output:**

```
arr = [['red', 685], ['green', 210], ['blue', 21], ['yellow', 245]];
```

---

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
if ( !arr.includes(color) ) {
    arr.push([color, number]);
} else {
    arr[color] = time;
}
```

But `!arr.includes(color)` condition is wrong. Because each item of `arr` is also an array. Anyway, how can I use `includes()` function on the first item of nested arrays?

Comment: do you only have one level of nesting?

Comment: @Maximus . . .yes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot directly use `includes` on nested array, however, you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on array.

```
arr.find(el => el[0] === color)
```

This will return the element of array found else `undefined`. The returned value can be used to update the second element in the array.

```js
var arr = [
  ['red', 685],
  ['green', 210],
  ['blue', 65]
];
var color = 'blue';
var number = 21;


function upsert(array, color, number) {
  var exists = arr.find(el => el[0] === color);

  if (exists) {
    exists[1] = number;
  } else {
    arr.push([color, number]);
  }
}

upsert(arr, color, number);
console.log(arr);


var color = 'yellow';
var number = 245;
upsert(arr, color, number);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Your approach seems great .. but it's a bit vague to implement it on my own example.

Comment: @stack I've added live demo.

Comment: good answer, works fine. I wonder how the part with el[0] works and why it still finds the element it even though its not the first element in the parent array.

Comment: @solaire In find el is the element in the parent array. As colour is first element in array, el[0] refers to the colour

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate the array and update the value if found, else push a new value

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [['red', 685], ['green', 210], ['blue', 65]];
console.log(updateArray(arr, 'blue', 21));

function updateArray(arr, color, value)
{
  var isFound = false;
  arr = arr.map( function(item){
     if( item[0] == color )
     {
       isFound = true;
       item[1] = value;
     }
     return item;
  });
  if ( !isFound )
  {
    arr.push([color, value]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a loop that cycles through the array because, as you pointed out yourself, each element of the array is itself an array.

If you do:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   if ( !arr[i].includes(color) ) {
       arr.push([color, number]);
   } else {
       arr[i][1] = time;
   }
}
```

This way you are checking if the array at position `i` has the color, if it doesn't you push a new array into the array, otherwise you change the array value at index 1 of the array `i`